# How to recover files from a Pixel 3 XL that cannot boot anymore

Tags: recovery-mode, bootloader, google-pixel-3-xl

My Pixel 3 XL is up-to-date regarding the OTA updates i.e. I have the latest firmware installed.
I've never done anything special regarding "tweaking", such as enabling the developer mode i.e. the developer mode is unfortunately not enabled.

I was browsing the Internet and the phone suddenly rebooted unexpectedly. Then it was in a reboot loop. I pressed power and volume down buttons to enter the boot menu.
The boot loop stopped but I was unable to do anything to make my phone boot properly again. In the recovery menu, there is no option to wipe the cache partition.
There should be roughly 400 MB of free space on the phone. I was thinking that maybe this could have been the cause of the issue.

When the phone is off and not plugged to the charger, the percentage of battery decreases. When the charger is plugged, the percentage of battery does not decrease but does not increase either. It seems I cannot charge the phone anymore. Currently remains 13%.

When the phone is off and I press the power button, the Google logo shows up and the progress bar below has just time to appear before the phone vibrates and goes off.

I don't care much saving the phone, but it's extremely important to me to be able to recover the photos it contains (standard DCIM folder).
Most of what I found googleing so far is about wiping the cache partition, but there is no such option on my Pixel 3 XL.
Since the developer mode (USB debugging) was not enabled when the phone was working fine, I cannot use adb to pull files. I can sideload though. As far as I understood, in my situation it is not possible to enable the developer mode.
I've just heard about TeamWin Recovery Project, and still trying to figure out if this can help me.

How can I, at least, backup my photos?
Of course the best would be able to boot the phone normally, but really my first goal is to save my photos.
Is there a way to reflash the firmware with the same version, or another version, without losing data, just like what happens on a regular update e.g. when a new Android version is deployed?

EDIT: I was wrong, the percentage of battery dcreases even when the charger is plugged, meaning that soon I won't be able to even turn the phone on.

Comment: flashing OTA zip from recovery menu is possible, not sure it will fix

Comment: The berry charging problem may be coincidence but it may also be the actual cause. Assuming the battery (or it's controller) is near death that could explain the sudden reboot and the boot loop (the power drops and the CPU resets). That you can't charge the battery could be also indicate a battery problem. Have you tried to boot while charger is connected? If that does not help replacing the battery may make the phone bootable again.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer, yes, the phone is now permanently plugged to the charger because that's the only way not to drop to 0%.
I did try to boot with the charger plugged but it did not help. I ordered a brand new battery on Ali Express and will try to replace it as soon as I receive it.

Comment: Thanks alecxs for your comment. Since I already have the latest version of the system, will the phone accept to flash OTA again with the same version?

Comment: @Robert: is the controller of the battery on the battery itself, meaning if I replace the battery I'll replace the controller too? Otherwise, how do I replace the controller if its death is the root cause of my problem?

Comment: The chance that the controller is the problem and not the battery is in my opinion very very low. A bad battery is a very common problem on Smartphones.

Comment: disassembly device and charge battery with external charger like [this](https://www.joom.com/products/5c0f96a66ecda80101d6a0a1). try from recovery with next OTA

Comment: @Robert: you were right! It was the battery. I ordered a new one and replaced the original one, and now my phone works just fine! I managed to backup everything. Thanks a lot for the hint!